# How can I rename methods with metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have five pictures for my profile model. I want to make it DRY. I have this code:

```
@profile.picture1 = set_selfies(params[:profile]["picture#{1}"])
```

I have a method that processes images/selfies xP, but any picture is an attribute of my `Profile` object. How can I rename `@profile.picture1`, `picture2`, ... `picture 5` dynamically with metaprogramming?

Comment: I think you're getting downvoted because you're not using a proper one to many relationship like you should be in this instance. If you want to do this the proper way, you need to create a table `pictures` with a `profile_id` and a model `Picture` that `belongs_to :profile` and and `Profile` that `has_many :pictures`. You really need to take a deeper look at the concepts of OO programming in order to better understand the best solution to problem you're trying to solve. railscasts.com is a great place to start

Comment: spickermann pretty much nailed it. If the example you used is really the extend of what you're up to, then metaprogramming is a bit of hammering in thumbtacks with sledge hammers.

Comment: and also what Mike said.

Comment: You have reason, but the application was built in this form u.u, I'm single can refactor the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send) with string interpolation seems to be the simplest solution:

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  @profile.send("picture#{i}=", set_selfies[:profile]["picture#{i}"])
end
```